# Heegard diagrams for three-manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, floer-homology, heegaard-floer-homology

I have a basic question about the Heegaard diagrams involved in providing a framework
for calculation of Floer-Homology of three-manifolds.

Typically such diagrams look like Figure 1 and Figure 2 [here](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Poincar%C3%A9%27s_homology_sphere) or these two ([Image1](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/A-genus-1genus-1-Heegaard-diagram-arising-from-the-HKM-procedure-applied-to-the-open-book_fig9_281576305) or [Image2](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/A-Heegaard-diagram-for-the-identity-mapping-class-on-S-the-left-and-right-hand-side_fig1_51916580)) from researchgate network.

And I would thankful if anybody could try to explain how to "read" this diagrams
to a non-topologist.

We see a compact surface, which is probably assumed to be the boundary of certain
three-manifold, and theory of compact surfaces states that this surface
is up to homeomorphism always a connect
sum of $g$ tori for $g \ge 1$. Looking at images in Image2 in last two links we
find two sets of $g$ disjoint curves ("team red" $\alpha_0,..., \alpha_g$ and
"team blue" $\beta_0,..., \beta_g$).

Now how does this information provide instructions to build a three-manifold?

My non-expert guess is that this data tells us: Start with two identical disjoint three-manifolds which have two $g$-tori as surfaces and the data provided by these
Heegaard diagrams is nothing else than instructions how to glue the two
three-manifolds along the surfaces. The instruction says probably that
the curve $\alpha_i$ of one surface has to be glued homeomorphically with
$\beta_i$ for other surface. And seemingly if we know all pairs of curves $\alpha_i$ and
$\beta_i$ are glued together, then the gluing of the two surfaces
is already uniquely determined up to homeomorphism and therefore we know how to glue the two disjoint three-manifold also the boundary.

Is this exactly the correct way to read a Heegaard diagram? Does there exist a more
conventional way? Sorry, if the question is too elementary, I'm not an
algebraic topologist and the motivation of this question is pure curiosity.

Comment: Start with $\Sigma \times I$. For each $\alpha$ curve (which you ought to thicken into an annulus, which you can do in a way which is unique up too isotopy), you glue on a copy of $D^2 \times I$ by pasting $S^1 \times I$ along the thickened $\alpha$ curve inside of $\Sigma \times \{0\}$. Do the same thing for the $\beta$ curves inside of $\Sigma \times \{1\}$. What you have produced is a compact 3-manifold with boundary $S^2 \sqcup S^2$; glue on 3-balls to make this a closed manifold. Gompf and Stipsicz have a good discussion.

Comment: I’ve taken the liberty of editing your title, because I don’t think anyone who studies 3-manifolds calls them “3-folds”.

Comment: You may also look at the first three chapters of beautiful paper of P. Ozsváth and Z. Szabó: http://math.mit.edu/~petero/Introduction.pdf

Comment: @MikeMiller: You mean it in the sense that you glue along each thickened tubulus of every 
$\alpha_i \subset \Sigma \times {0}$ a $2$-handle and them the same game 
for $\beta_j \subset \Sigma \times {1}$. What I still not understand is why
the $3$-manifold obtained by this construction has boundary $S^2 \sqcup S^2$?

Comment: You are at each stage performing a handle attachment, which changes the boundary by a surgery along the attaching sphere. Check that this process reduces the genus by 1 every time you do a handle attachment. You do it g times. Again, G&S is a good source.

Comment: @Mike Miller: Hi, sorry for repeated annoying but I would like to know following 
aspect regarding your construction: Recently in Sivek's Lecture 24 (http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~ssivek/courses/273notes/lecture24.pdf) I found
a descripion of explicite construction of $3$-folds by the
Heegaard data that works as follows (page 1):

Comment: He wrote: Given a Heegaard decompsition $Y = H_{\alpha} \cup_{\Sigma} H_{\beta}$
, we can desribe the decomposition completely in terms of curves on 
the surface $\Sigma$. We construct $H_{\alpha}$ by
attaching $g$ $1$-handles to $\Sigma \times [0,1]$ along curves 
$\alpha_1 \times \{0\}, ..., \alpha_g \times \{0\}$ and filling
in the resulting $S^2$ on the boundary with a ball, 
and similarly we construct $H_{\beta}$
by ataching $g$ $2$-handles to$\Sigma \times [0,1]$ along curves 
$\beta_1 \times \{1\}, ..., \beta_g \times \{1\}$ and
filling in the remaining $S_2$ with a ball. [...]

Comment: This construction looks very similar to yours except that
you attatched to $\beta_1 \times \{1\}, ..., \beta_g \times \{1\}$
but as well $\alpha_1 \times \{0\}, ..., \alpha_g \times \{0\}$
in both cases $2$-handles. (more precisely to the thickings (=annuli) of
$\alpha_i \times \{0\}, \beta_j \times \{1\}$). But the important point is that you worked 
on both sides on $\Sigma \times \{0\}$ and 
$\Sigma \times \{1\}$ with $2$-handles, while Sivek 
attatched on  $\Sigma \times \{0\}$ $1$-handles and on 
$\Sigma \times \{1\}$ $2$-handles.

Comment: And that's what I not understand. Do we obtain in yours and Sivek's
construction the same object (if yes, why?) 
or do Sivek's notes contain an error?
Expecially I don't know how Sivek intends to attatch $1$-handles
along $\alpha_1 \times \{0\}, ..., \alpha_g \times \{0\}$.

Comment: Sivek is thinking from the ground up: you start with a 0-handle, you attach g 1-handles, and then what you have is diffeomorphic to the handlebody $H_\alpha$ (the $\alpha$ curves being the boundary of the core disc of the 1-handle). Using a diffeomorphism $\partial(H_\alpha) \to S_g$ sending those circles to the $\alpha$ curves, you then attach the 2-handles along the $\beta$ curves. This is the perspective that Morse theory suggests. See maybe Oszvath-Szabo intro lecture on HF. 

I think you'd be best off finding a topologist who is willing to work through these constructions in person.

Answer (score 5):

Chapter four of "Knots, Links, Braids and 3-Manifolds" by Prasolov and Sossinsky gives a highly readable (and nicely illustrated) introduction to three-manifolds via Heegaard splittings.  Another, more classical, reference is chapter two of "Three-manifolds" by Hempel.  Note that Hempel calls handlebodies "cubes with handles".

Answer (score 3):

You are probably familiar with definitions and theorems. But I prefer to write those for completeness. And also excuse for a paint-like drawing. I hope that they will be useful.

A *handlebody of genus $g$* is a $3$-manifold constructed from the standart $3$-ball $B^3$ by adding $g$ copies of $1$-handles $B^2 \times B^1$. It is denoted by $H$ and $\partial H \approx \Sigma_g$ where $\Sigma_g$ is a genus $g$ surface, see the following figures.[image]

Let $Y$ be a $3$-manifold. A *Heegaard splitting* of $Y$ is a decomposition of $Y$ such that

- $Y=H_0 \cup H_1$ where $H_0$ and $H_1$ are handlebodies,
- $\partial
     H_0 = \partial H_1 = \Sigma_g$.

**Theorem(Singer, 1933):** Any closed oriented 3-manifold $Y$ admits a Heegaard splitting.

The genus $g$-surface $\Sigma_g$ is constructed from $S^2 = \mathbb{R}^2 \cup \{ \infty \}$ by attaching $g$ copies of $1$-handles, where we draw attaching spheres as pairs of matching disks.

[image]

So the followings are Heegaard splittings of $S^3$ and $S^1 \times S^2$ respectively:

[image]

The following is for a Heegaard diagram of lens space $L(5,2)$:

[image]

And the last scheme is for the famous Poincaré homology sphere $\Sigma(2,3,5)$:

[image]